# Eclipse MakeGood Error: PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase class is not available

Tags: php, eclipse, phpunit, xdebug, makegood

I've been having an issue setting up XDebug (2.6.0) to work with PHPUnit (6.0.13) in Eclipse Neon (4.6.3). I've had XDebug working within my browser, and have had PHPUnit working from the command line, however am unable to get the two working together.

I'm working within a Vagrant VM running Ubuntu, with OSX as my main system.

XDebug is installed globally through Vagrant and PHPUnit is installed via Composer. In my Project Settings, I have pointed a PHP Executable to `/usr/bin/php`, using the system default .ini file., however this is the file on my machine, rather than the file on the VM, so I don't know if I need to adjust this, but nothing I read mentioned it?

The issue I am having is that my 'MakeGood' tab is showing the error 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase class is not available. Fix...' even though I have included the `vendor/autoload.php` file within the Project Preferences.  I have also tried setting up a custom library pointing towards the `vendors/` folder, as I saw suggested on a blog post, however it didn't help anything.  So any suggestions as to what else to try would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried looking around on here and further across the web, and most of the resources I can find talk only about setting it up referencing through PEAR, however that obviously doesn't work with Composer.

As always, thanks for any help you can provide.

**Edit:**  Just in case it makes any difference, my tests are stored in `tests/`, with the namespace `\App\Test` and my classes in `resources/src/` with the namespace `\App`.

Comment: Here's the [release notes](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/Release-Announcement-for-PHPUnit-6.0.0) for PHPUnit 6.0. _"PHPUnit's units of code are now namespaced. For instance, PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase is now PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase"_

Comment: review this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40341950/how-do-i-deal-with-class-phpunit-framework-testcase-not-found-error/42030919#42030919)